# Does Hyperledger Besu support Plasma?

Tags: nodes, plasma, besu

Does the Besu client support Plasma?

I guess this question could also be asked about other clients such as Geth and Parity as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plasma is not directly a client feature. It's an architecture to facilitate certain scenarios.

How a Plasma implementation is actually done is a separate issue and I don't think any Ethereum client has built-in Plasma support. It's just something that is built around the Ethereum infrastructure and therefore any client can be used.

Actually most of the functionality in Plasma is outside the blockchain and only some small interactions with the blockchain are required.

Comment: It seems that a specific piece of software is still required to interact with the plasma chains. I don't know however if this soft provides the connection to the main Ethereum chain too or if it connects through a regular Ethereum client via RPC and only handles the plasma part. Most Plasma projects are archived on Github and it seems that it's not a very active development subject

Comment: The connection is left to "traditional" means most likely - I don't see any reason for the projects to start implementing their own clients. And yes, Plasma development is quieting down due to various issues.

Comment: Yes, that's what looks the most efficient way to proceed. Would you have some links to the remaining active projects for me to check this?

Comment: I really don't know which projects are active still. Here are some keywords: Plasma Cash, MonoPlasma, Loom network DAppChain

Comment: if plasma is not effective then what can be the other solutions for scaling ethereum solutions .

Comment: If you have further questions please post a new question. Extended discussions in the comments section are discouraged. Thanks!

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/79630/scaling-solutions-for-ethereum

Answer (score 1):

**The Besu client supports**

The Besu client supports common smart contract and Dapp development, deployment, and operational use cases, using tools such as Truffle, Remix, and web3j. The client supports common JSON-RPC API methods such as eth, net, web3, debug, and miner.

Besu doesn’t support key management inside the client. You can use EthSigner with Besu to provide access to your key store and sign transactions.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how this answers the question